# how does getline() work in terms of pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, getline

I want to know how the getline() function works in terms of pointers.
In the code below,for the while condition, how is getline() not starting from the very beginning of ss after each loop, but right after last delimiter it had encountered. I thought that ss is altered every time getline() works, but i realized that it is not true because printing ss.str() after each loop always gives the original stringstream. So i am assuming it must be having to do something with the pointers.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

vector<int> parseInts(string str) {

    stringstream ss(str);
    vector<int> result;
    string ele;
    while(getline(ss, ele, ','))
    {
        result.push_back(atoi(ele.c_str()));
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    string str;
    cin >> str;
    vector<int> integers = parseInts(str);
    for(int i = 0; i < integers.size(); i++) {
        cout << integers[i] << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The stream has a "current position" which is updated. The contents of the stream don't change.

Comment: extending on @molbdnilo 's comment, pay attention to the output of `ss.tellg()` and `ss.tellp()` as you add to and read from `ss`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought that `ss` is altered every time `getline()` works,

That's true.

> but i realized that it is not true because printing `ss.str()` after each loop always gives the original stringstream.

That doesn't mean nothing's altered.  A `stringstream`'s state includes the textual content, positions within that content (and more): when you call `.str()` you get the entire content, but when you parse some out with `getline` you change the position state used by future queries, as well as - potentially - the `fail`/`bad`/`eof` stream state.

Answer (score 0):

You can find more info for example from [gcc src code of std::istream](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-3.3/istream_8tcc-source.html#l01180) in line 01180 as you can see

`__c = __sb->sbumpc();`

read next symbol from input stream by runing function `sbumpc()` [from here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-api-4.5/a01048_source.html#l00294) which is reading current symbol from streambuf

`__ret = traits_type::to_int_type(*this->gptr());`
 
than increase current value of pointer on current position from program should read next data

`this->gbump(1)`

and than return next next symbol from stream so operation `getline()` just change inner one pointer of streambuf. But when you run `str()` for stringstream read all data from streambuf  and not using changed pointer. Hope this helps you also can find more examples and info in src of gcc